работа с файлами в unity web
Я пишу прогу для работы с файлами и для выбора файлов решил использовать ассет Runtime File Browser. Но в веб версии программа не видит файловую систему компьютера, а только какую-то "свою" локальную.
Как можно взаимодействовать с файлами компьютера?

Ты из браузера хочешь файлы посмотреть?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

@u111 да, именно так

Мне кажется, что это невозможно.

@u111 ладно, спасибо за ответ

@u111 вообще возможно, у vscode онлайн как раз можно. Уже есть апи для этого.

Ты путаешь тёплое с мягким. Вэб в браузере может попросил операционную систему, открыть окно выбора файла с некоторыми параметрами, но сам просматривать директории не может.

Только поедставь, что было бы, если любой сайт мог посмотреть, что у тебя на жёстком диске... Слава богу, это не настолько просто.
